# What tense should I use past simple or past continuous?

Tags: tense

He_____ (ride) a horse when he was a child.
She ______ (sing) in a school choir many years ago.

Answer (score 2):

Past simple is used to express habitual actions, whereas past continuous is used to describe something that was in progress at the time something else happened.

> He **rode** a horse when he was a child - habitual
>
> He **was riding** a horse when he first saw her - in progress

You can also use the expression "used to" to describe a habitual action

> He **used to** ride a horse when he was a child - habitual